# What is the best way to transfer tokens to/from the internal balance using OpenZeppelin?

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts, solidity-0.8.x

I'm using OpenZeppelin as base for my contracts.

I know it don't allow me to access `_balances` directly, only using `transfer()`. But this function only allow transfer tokens from/to the sender, hidding the original `transfer()`:

```
function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
} 

function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
}
```

This way I can't access `_balances[]` directly and it is a GOOD thing! But ....

I have an use case that I really need to access `_balances[]` or someone shows me another way to do it. Let's see :

- I have 4 tokens: Gold, Wood, Iron and Clay.
- Gold is the only owner of the other 3 ( Gold created them in its constructor ).
- I need to call 3 functions in Gold contract to give to user Wood, Iron and Clay in exchange of Gold.
  The user call `buyWood( goldAmount )`, `buyIron( goldAmount )` and `buyClay( goldAmount )`and I need to take `goldAmount` from his Gold balance and put `goldAmount` ( 1:1 for now) in his resource balance calling each resource's methods.
- In other hand when the user calls `sell(amount)` in any resource I need to take the way back giving him this amount in Gold ( 1:1 for now) and take back this amount in resources from his resource balance.

My problem is: since I can't handle internal balance map directly, I'm messing something with OpenZeppelin's `transfer()` wrapper function. Also tried `transferFrom()` but things only got worse.

The error I'm receiving is something like "The sender cannot be null" (I can't check it right now) in "buy***()" methods.

Here is the code:

**Gold.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.1.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.1.0/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "./resource.sol";

contract Gold is Ownable, ERC20 {
    Resource public _wood;
    Resource public _iron;
    Resource public _clay;

    constructor ()  ERC20("Gold", "W-GLD") {
        _mint( msg.sender, 1000 * (10 ** uint256( decimals() ) ) );
        _wood = new Resource("Wood", "W-WOD");
        _iron = new Resource("Iron", "W-IRN");
        _clay = new Resource("Clay", "W-CLY");
    }

    function buyWood(uint _value) external {
        transferFrom(msg.sender, owner(), _value);
        _wood._give(msg.sender, _value);
    }
    
    function buyIron(uint _value) external {
        transferFrom(msg.sender, owner(), _value);
        _iron._give(msg.sender, _value);
    }

    function buyClay(uint _value) external {
        transferFrom(msg.sender, owner(), _value);
        _clay._give(msg.sender, _value);
    }
    
    function _give( address _to, uint _value ) external {
        require( msg.sender == address( _wood ) || msg.sender == address( _clay ) || msg.sender == address( _iron ) );
        transferFrom( owner(), _to, _value );
    }    

    function decimals() public view virtual override returns (uint8) {
        return 5;
    }  
}
```

**Resource.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.1.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.1.0/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "./gold.sol";

contract Resource is Ownable, ERC20 {

    
    constructor (string memory name, string memory symbol ) ERC20(name,symbol) {
        
    }
    
    function _give(address _to, uint _value) external onlyOwner {
        transferFrom( owner(),  _to, _value );
    } 
    
    function sell(uint _value) external {
        transferFrom(msg.sender, owner(), _value);
        Gold( owner() )._give(msg.sender, _value);
    } 
    
  
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops!!
My code is correct.
I just forgot to mint some coins in the Resource's constructor ...